# Why my simple Spring Boot application fails to deploy on Heroku?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

I'm just trying to deploy a very simple spring boot app in Heroku, but despite showing no errors in the deploy log, it doesn't works.

When I open it in the browser at [the deployed address](https://hello-heroku789.herokuapp.com/), it shows this message:

****Whitelabel Error Page**

*This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Apr 05 08:47:38 UTC 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).***

I am using Git Hub connect ad Heroku deployment method.
This is the code I deployed from my public repository:
https://github.com/Picpippo/hello-heroku789.git

There are no errors in heroku, on the contrary it shows me all green ticks.
So, what's wrong with it?
Thanks

Comment: can you share url details, the complete url which you are trying to access in browser?

Comment: Yes, this is: https://hello-heroku789.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is nothing mapped on the root URL. However There is a controller listening on /hello path.
Try this URL: https://hello-heroku789.herokuapp.com/hello